# Reopen the active window when it's closed in MACOSX

Tags: macos, swift

I was trying to open the window when the closed button was pressed and the user clicks the app icon on the dock.I know how to do that.Now i want to get the currently active window that the user closed and open it up again.Any ideas?
This is the code i m using to open a particular login window.

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(theApplication: NSApplication!,hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {

    AppManager.sharedInstance.login?.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
    return true
}
```

With this code only the login window controller is reopened after closing it.I want to close and reopen the currently active window.